# Laravel error when parsing variables in the side bar

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sidebar

Can you parse data into laravel layouts? I get an error when I want to implement a dynamic siderbar based on a database. Here's my code

Controller

```
public function side_kategori()
    {
        $kategori = Kategori::all();
        return view('admin/layouts/sidebar', ['kategori'=>$kategori]);
    }
```

Model

```
 protected $table = 'tb_kategori';
 protected $primaryKey = 'id_kategori';
```

View

```
/*location ('admin/layouts/sidebar.blade.php')*/
           <ul class="children collapse" id="sub-item-1">
                @foreach($kategori as $kat)
                <li>
                    <a href="/kategori/detil_katgori/{{$kat->id_kategori}}">{{$kat->nama_kategori}}</a>
                </li>
                @endforeach
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="margin-right: 4px"></i>Add</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Thats my sidebar.blade.php file, and this is my App Layout (contains all componets likes Header, SideBar, and Footer)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>E-Upacara</title>
</head>
<body>
    @include('admin/layouts.head')

    @include('admin/layouts.navigator')

/*I think the error starts here*/
    @include('admin/layouts.sidebar')
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 main">
        @yield('konten')
    </div>

@include('admin/layouts.footer')

</body>
</html>
```

Error

```
Undefined variable: kategori (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\si_laravel\resources\views\admin\layouts\sidebar.blade.php)
```

I still think, is my idea wrong to implement this ?

Comment: At the top of sidebare.blade.php file, place `dd($kategori)` and erload the page. Copy and paste the content here. The goal is to find out what gets sent to then template

Comment: This the error code :
`
Undefined variable: kategori (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\si_laravel\resources\views\admin\layouts\sidebar.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\si_laravel\resources\views\admin\layouts\sidebar.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\si_laravel\resources\views\admin\layouts\sidebar.blade.php)

in 95392c0080b086653ee916f56fe2d3c3b9f75580.php line 30
`
I only take 2 error that i think is important
Thank u for ur response @djunehor

Comment: This means `$kategori` is not getting to the view at all. Change `return view('admin/layouts/sidebar', ['kategori'=>$kategori]);` to `return view('admin/layouts/sidebar', compact('kategori');` and leave the dd() in the sidebar template. See if anything changes.

Comment: The way he is passing it in is fine, this looks like it may be a problem with the Route. Is the `side_kategori` function getting executing when you hit the route? Post what your `routes/web.php` looks like

Comment: It's still error same as before. I think the variable can't parse into layouts because layouts is using by "all view" and this "all view" confuse what the variable it is

Comment: In my [routes/web.php] is not related to the layouts. Because layouts is using by the file in view (im using @extends and @section). I think the [routes/web.php[ its not related in this case. Thank u for ur response

Comment: Place a dd() in the controller method. Let's identify if that method is called at all

Comment: I have two controller here, the 'Admin' and the 'Kategori'. So where i should put the dd() code ?. Sorry im just a newbie in laravel, and i want to learn it. Thanks btw @djunehor

Comment: Place dd() in the controller method you posted in the question. Place it just before the return statement. We're trying to figure out if that method executes at all

Comment: I have done it. and I get an error like this: 
Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\Kategori because the name is already in use. 
What im doing is make another view (dummy view) to return what write in my "Kategori Controller". Thanks btw @djunehor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variables into your sidebar layout. First of all, in your subviews that extend the sidebar layout, return the `kategori` variable with the controller like you normally do. Then you can pass the variable with `@extends('admin.layouts.sidebar', ['kategori' => $kategori])`

If you want the  `$kategori` to be shared across *ALL* views, then you can do the following:

Go to `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`, inside `public function boot()` add

```
$kategori = Kategori::all();
 view()->share('kategori', $kategori);
```

This will share your categories across all views.

Make sure to include the Model with `use App\Kategori;` at the top.

**NOTE**: This is not ideal from a performance standpoint, as on every single view request you are querying the database for `$kategori`. You should really look into View composers to achieve this:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers

However, if `$kategori` is small (maybe retrieving 20 or so categories), it's not a huge hit to take.

Comment: It's still error, same as before. I think i could share the extends and the yield in my program. You can check now in 'View' section in above

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. U help me. Again Thank u

Comment: But theres a question. If i want to view another data that not related in table and model 'Kategori', can laravel do it? like globally in this case